# RStudio not loading with Git installed

Tags: git, rstudio

I'm trying to install Git to use with Rstudio but once I install Git I can't load RStudio.  I can open it but all that shows up is the tool bar at the top and I can't click on any of the options, the rest is white. I've used RStudio reliably but never Git, I tried installing it once before but had this same problem until I uninstalled Git (every time I uninstall Git RStudio goes back to normal and very time I reinstall it I get the same problem loading RStudio). I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both but still have the same problem. How can I use RStudio and Git together without stopping RStudio from working?

[This is what I get when i try to open RStudio after installing Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQl15.png)